# platform.quarkus.native.builder-image in PropertiesConfigSource does not map to any root

Tags: quarkus

Currently I'm updating my application from 2.16.1.Final version quarkus to 3.6.3. An now when I run @QuarkusTest it fails with io.smallrye.config.ConfigValidationException: Configuration validation failed:SRCFG00050: platform.quarkus.native.builder-image in PropertiesConfigSource does not map to any root. Has anybody come across this?

It seems that some configuration in application.properties is missed.
I have a multi module project and this is build.gradle for the module where tests fail.

```
    plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")
    id("io.quarkus")
}

    dependencies {
        api(project(":proj1"))
        implementation(project(":proj2"))
        implementation(project(":proj3"))
        implementation(project(":proj4"))
        implementation(project(":proj5"))
        implementation(project(":proj6"))
        implementation(project(":proj7"))
        implementation(project(":proj8"))
    implementation(project(":proj9"))

    implementation(enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"))
    implementation('io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin')
    implementation('io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive')
    implementation('io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson')
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler")
    implementation('io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi')
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.6.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.2")
    implementation('io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-instrumentation-annotations')
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus")

    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.18.0")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.18.0")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.18.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.16.0")
    implementation("io.smallrye.reactive:smallrye-mutiny-vertx-kafka-client") {
        exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    }

    api("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0")
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.8.2")
    implementation("org.apache.jena:jena-core:4.10.0")
    implementation("org.apache.jena:jena-text:4.10.0")
    implementation("org.apache.jena:jena-arq:4.10.0")
    implementation("org.apache.jena:jena-querybuilder:4.10.0")
    implementation("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.0.1")


    testImplementation(project(":proj10"))
    testImplementation(project(":proj11"))
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
    testImplementation('io.rest-assured:rest-assured')
    testImplementation("org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.4")
    testImplementation("de.bwaldvogel:mongo-java-server:1.43.0")
    testImplementation(project(path: ':proj12', configuration: 'testArtifacts'))
    testImplementation(testFixtures(project(':proj13')))
    testImplementation(testFixtures(project(':proj14')))
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.17.6")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupites:1.17.6")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:cockroachdb:1.17.6")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:kafka:1.17.6")
    testImplementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.11.0")
    testImplementation('io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

project.generateGitInfo(":proj")
```

Comment: Have you tried performing the update with the tooling Quarkus provides?

Comment: @geoand yes, I tried to update project with the toll first but it failed with errors.

Comment: What does your `pom.xml` or `gradle.build` look like?

Comment: @geoand added build.gradle to the post. Any clue is highly appreciated.